# Is there a way to transform a data.table so that unique row elements become column names and then show element counts?

Tags: r, data.table, reshape

I have the following data.table:

```
structure(list(index = structure(c(1571270400, 1571356800, 1571616000, 
1571702400, 1571788800, 1571875200, 1571961600, 1572220800, 1572307200, 
1572393600), tzone = "", tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), A = structure(c(10L, 10L, 7L, 7L, 9L, 9L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L), .Label = c("12", "13", "14", "21", "24", "31", "34", 
"41", "42", "43"), class = "factor"), AA = structure(c(2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L), .Label = c("12", "13", "14", 
"21", "23", "24", "31", "32", "34", "41", "42", "43"), class = "factor"), 
    AAC = structure(c(6L, 11L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, NA, NA, 7L
    ), .Label = c("12", "13", "14", "21", "23", "24", "31", "34", 
    "41", "42", "43"), class = "factor"), AAL = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L), .Label = c("12", "13", 
    "14", "21", "23", "24", "31", "32", "34", "41", "42", "43"
    ), class = "factor")), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -10L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x5614347b5790>, sorted = "index")
```

Here is how this data looks in the table -

```
         index  A B    C   D
 1: 2019-10-17 43 13   24  13
 2: 2019-10-18 43 13   43  13
 3: 2019-10-21 34 13   31  13
 4: 2019-10-22 34 13   31  13
 5: 2019-10-23 42 13   31  13
 6: 2019-10-24 42 31   31  31
 7: 2019-10-25 21 31   31  31
 8: 2019-10-28 21 31 <NA>  31
 9: 2019-10-29 21 31 <NA>  31
10: 2019-10-30 21 31   31  31
```

I want to transform it so that the unique elements in rows become column names and these columns then show the frequency of these elements.

```
         index  13 21  24 31 34 42 43 <NA>
 1: 2019-10-17   2  0   1  0  0  0  1  0
 2: 2019-10-18   2  0   0  0  0  0  2  0
 3: 2019-10-21   2  0   0  1  1  0  0  0
 4: 2019-10-22   2  0   0  1  1  0  0  0
 5: 2019-10-23   2  0   0  1  0  1  0  0
 6: 2019-10-24   3  0   0  0  0  1  0  0
 7: 2019-10-25   3  1   0  0  0  0  0  0
 8: 2019-10-28   2  1   0  0  0  0  0  1
 9: 2019-10-29   2  1   0  0  0  0  0  1
10: 2019-10-30   3  1   0  0  0  0  0  0
```

I am sure there should be a clever way to do this using reshape or data.table functions. A pointer in the right direction will be very helpful.

Comment: I think you need to `melt` and then `dcast`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can `melt` the dataset into 'long' format by specifying the `id.var` and then reshape it back to 'wide' format with `dcast` while specifying the `fun.aggregate` as `length`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(melt(dt, id.var = 'index'), as.IDate(index) ~ value, length)
#          index NA 13 21 24 31 34 42 43
# 1: 2019-10-16  0  2  0  1  0  0  0  1
# 2: 2019-10-17  0  2  0  0  0  0  0  2
# 3: 2019-10-20  0  2  0  0  1  1  0  0
# 4: 2019-10-21  0  2  0  0  1  1  0  0
# 5: 2019-10-22  0  2  0  0  1  0  1  0
# 6: 2019-10-23  0  0  0  0  3  0  1  0
# 7: 2019-10-24  0  0  1  0  3  0  0  0
# 8: 2019-10-27  1  0  1  0  2  0  0  0
# 9: 2019-10-28  1  0  1  0  2  0  0  0
#10: 2019-10-29  0  0  1  0  3  0  0  0
```

NOTE: If we don't want the `NA` column, specify the `na.rm = TRUE` in `melt`

Answer (score 1):

Here’s a solution using the newer `tidyverse` functions. It works great with data.tables too, though.

1. First we convert from wide to long form

   - The `cols` argument accepts tidyselect helpers to chose columns by name. `matches()` selects columns based on a regex. You can read more about them here in the manual found here: `?tidyselect::select_helpers`
2. Then we spread back to wide form
3. We use `values_fn` to apply the `length` function on the values. This will give the number of unique counts
4. Then we optionally replace `NA` with `0` in all numeric columns

Here’s the example

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = matches('^A'))) %>%              #convert to long form
  pivot_wider(id_cols = 'index', names_from = 'value', # Then spread wide again
              values_fn = list(value = length)) %>%    # return length of vals
  mutate_if(is.numeric, ~ ifelse(is.na(.), 0, .))      # replace NA with 0

# A tibble: 10 x 9
   index                `43`  `13`  `24`  `34`  `31`  `42`  `21`  `NA`
   <dttm>              <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 2019-10-16 17:00:00     1     2     1     0     0     0     0     0
 2 2019-10-17 17:00:00     2     2     0     0     0     0     0     0
 3 2019-10-20 17:00:00     0     2     0     1     1     0     0     0
 4 2019-10-21 17:00:00     0     2     0     1     1     0     0     0
 5 2019-10-22 17:00:00     0     2     0     0     1     1     0     0
 6 2019-10-23 17:00:00     0     0     0     0     3     1     0     0
 7 2019-10-24 17:00:00     0     0     0     0     3     0     1     0
 8 2019-10-27 17:00:00     0     0     0     0     2     0     1     1
 9 2019-10-28 17:00:00     0     0     0     0     2     0     1     1
10 2019-10-29 17:00:00     0     0     0     0     3     0     1     0
```

Comment: Since I have hundreds of columns, is there a way to make the statement `pivot_longer(c(A, AA, AAC, AAL))`, independent of column names?

Comment: @Saurabh Yeah, you can use tidyselect helpers to select the columns. `matches()` is the most versatile, as it lets you selects columns using a regex, but there is also `starts_with` and `ends_with`